# Detecting installed Visual Basic Power Packs in target system?

Tags: vb.net, registry

I wanna detect the version of installed Visual Basic Power Packs in target system.
How can I do it with Registry values (Windows from Win XP)?
Or, How can I check the version of `Visual Basic Power Packs` assembly , e.g : how I can check the version of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` assembly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which, if any, registry settings gets written when the power packs gets installed, but an easy way to find out is to set up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor all changes on a system and then install the power pack on there and you'll be able to see everything that gets written.

Edit: To get the version of an assembly, use [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) or [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) to load it and then get out the [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) using the [GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getname.aspx) method and the `AssemblyName` has a [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) property.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna create an install file , so I have to check the version of Visual Basic Power Packs.How can I check the version of its assembly ?

Comment: @Mohammad: Edited my answer to show how you can get version info from an assembly.